# Converting CSV to PyG graph

Tags: python-3.x, csv, graph, pytorch-geometric

I have a CSV dataset as shown below:

| index | s_key | identifier | edge_pairs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [1683, 1684, 1685, 1686, 1688, 1689, 1691, 1692, 1693, 1694, 1695, 1696, 1697, 1698, 1699, 12740] | [0, 0] | [[0, 793]] |
| 1 | [9774, 9800, 9807, 9818, 9831, 9834, 9836, 9837, 9839, 9843, 13723, 21455] | [0, 1] | [[1, 3], [1, 123], [1, 152], [1, 163], [1, 266], [1, 337], [1, 351], [1, 352], [1, 355], [1, 606], [1, 869], [1, 962], [1, 1125], [1, 1412], [1, 1413], [1, 1417], [1, 1435], [1, 1440], [1, 1454], [1, 1572], [1, 1588], [1, 1653], [1, 1726], [1, 1898], [1, 2075], [1, 2076], [1, 2166], [1, 2297], [1, 2299], [1, 2319], [1, 2327], [1, 2330], [1, 2335], [1, 2393], [1, 2395], [1, 2400], [1, 2405], [1, 2486]] |
| 3 | [2156, 2896, 3028, 4023, 4256, 6787, 7265, 8882, 8970, 9831, 10959, 11268, 11341, 12601, 13737, 17264, 18906, 20430, 21747, 22228, 22229, 22512, 22841, 24049, 25104, 25394, 25731, 26045, 26103, 31121, 31522, 31839, 31851, 31859, 31872, 35527, 35547, 36538, 37150, 37345, 37692, 37888, 37895, 38962, 45332] | [0, 3] | [[3, 8], [3, 11], [3, 12], [3, 13], [3, 27], [3, 34], [3, 99], [3, 123], [3, 125], [3, 130], [3, 132], [3, 133], [3, 134], [3, 144], [3, 147], [3, 152], [3, 154], [3, 180], [3, 181], [3, 207]] |
| 4 | [25203, 25204, 25215, 25219, 25227, 25232, 25235, 25248, 25251, 25252, 25259, 25270] | [0, 4] | [[4, 215], [4, 322], [4, 342], [4, 793], [4, 1043], [4, 1127], [4, 1176], [4, 1454], [4, 2154], [4, 2284], [4, 2331], [4, 2400], [4, 2759], [4, 2920], [4, 3335]] |
| 5 | [27099, 27101, 27104, 27107, 27108, 27111, 27117, 27120, 27123, 27131, 27143, 27153, 27156, 27158, 27162, 27167, 27172, 27175, 27176, 27178, 27184, 27185] | [0, 5] | [[5, 8], [5, 239], [5, 378], [5, 1163], [5, 1220], [5, 1378], [5, 1422], [5, 1440], [5, 1636], [5, 1681], [5, 2190], [5, 2303], [5, 2399]] |

The `index` column represents each node.

The `edge_pairs` column represents the connection of each node.
For example: In Index `0`, the edge pair column: `[[0, 793]]` represents the connection of node 0 with Node 793 and so on.

I want to make a graph out of this CSV in a format that PyG accepts `data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index, y=y)`.
I am unsure of what to take as Node Features & Labels and how to represent the connection of edges between them.